# C# (Windows Phone Silverlight) String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a string like `2015-07-30T11:11:00+0200`. How can I parse it to `DateTime` object? `DateTime.Parse(string)` throws `null exception`, `ParseExact` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `DateTime` since your string has [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) part.

```
string s = "2015-07-30T11:11:00+0200";
DateTimeOffset dt;
if(DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //
}
```

Now, you have a `DateTimeOffset` as

```
30.07.2015 11:11:00 +02:00
```

If you wanna get it's `DateTime` part, you can use it's [`DateTimeOffset.DateTime` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns;

```
30.07.2015 11:11:00
```